MongoDB ignore read access for user
I don't know what is wrong but mongodb ignore restrict read and write roles.
I created DB "TESDB" and user "TestReadUser"
{
    "_id" : "admin.TestReadUser",
    "userId" : UUID("88c52a39-6834-4ce7-9232-de106a31e800"),
    "user" : "TestReadUser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "read",
            "db" : "TESTDB"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [ "SCRAM-SHA-1", "SCRAM-SHA-256" ]
}

But this user can create,drop, write etc ..
List of DB roles

Authetification in /etc/mongod.conf is enable
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /mongo-security/replicakeyfile.txt
  transitionToAuth: true

What is wrong, please ?

Did you restart the databases?
transitionToAuth is used only for transition. A mongod running with --transitionToAuth accepts both authenticated and non-authenticated connections. Clients connected to the mongod during this transition state can perform read, write, and administrative operations on any database.
Remove the transitionToAuth: true setting!
